RedHat Quay does not start on RHEL 9.4
I'm not super deep on troubleshooting yet, but I have fired up a brand new install of RHEL 9.4 minimal just to run RedHat Quay. I followed the instructions exactly as listed here, but when I run the command to kick it off it silently dies:
[root@quay-server ~]# podman run -d --rm -p 80:8080 -p 443:8443  --name=quay -v $QUAY/config:/conf/stack:Z -v $QUAY/storage:/datastorage:Z registry.redhat.io/quay/quay-rhel8:v3.11.1
02550ff6dea103c0012f7b3e5256a59962e756617631aad0597721d00f60bc72
[root@quay-server ~]# podman ps -a
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE       COMMAND     CREATED     STATUS      PORTS       NAMES
[root@quay-server ~]#

If I check the logs:
[root@quay-server ~]# podman logs 0dd6a61a7206
   __   __
  /  \ /  \     ______   _    _     __   __   __
 / /\ / /\ \   /  __  \ | |  | |   /  \  \ \ / /
/ /  / /  \ \  | |  | | | |  | |  / /\ \  \   /
\ \  \ \  / /  | |__| | | |__| | / ____ \  | |
 \ \/ \ \/ /   \_  ___/  \____/ /_/    \_\ |_|
  \__/ \__/      \ \__
                  \___\ by Red Hat
 Build, Store, and Distribute your Containers

Startup timestamp:
Mon Jun 10 20:30:42 UTC 2024

Running all default registry services
Running init script '/quay-registry/conf/init/certs_install.sh'
Running init script '/quay-registry/conf/init/client_certs.sh'
Running init script '/quay-registry/conf/init/copy_config_files.sh'
Running init script '/quay-registry/conf/init/d_validate_config_bundle.sh'
Validating Configuration
time="2024-06-10T20:30:42Z" level=fatal msg="open /quay-registry/conf/stack/config.yaml: no such file or directory"

but if I check the mount:
[root@quay-server ~]# cat $QUAY/config/config.yml
BUILDLOGS_REDIS:
    host: quay-server.openshift.lan
...SNIP...

it is there exactly as requested in the instructions.

Does it work if you replace -v $QUAY/config:/conf/stack:Z with -v $QUAY/config:/quay-registry/conf/stack:Z

No, I assume they're doing something under the hood to fix the paths, but that also doesn't work.

User incompetence.
Quay only accepts the .yaml extension and I only ever use .yml. Make sure you have the right extension.
